# How to turn on syntax highlighting for runsettings files in VS Code?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, runsettings

I'd like to have a better experience when writing my `test.runsettings` file for my **.Net** projects when using **VS Code**.

The `.runsettings` file contains xml so I assume it's feasible without extensions.

Note that I don't mind installing extensions though, especially if they offer functionality related to `.runsettings`, such as auto-completion of common tags and attributes (like `<DataCollectors>` or `<Logger>`).